# Is it better to call .enqueue in a normal function or .execute in a kotlin suspend function?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

Here is what I already know:
Retrofit has the `enqueue` function and the `execute` function. The `enqueue` function executes on a different (background) thread and then returns the response using the callback. The `execute` function executes on the calling Thread and returns the response directly. `enqueue` can be called on the UI Thread while `execute` shouldn't be called on the UI Thread.

But I am now wondering, which of the following two options is better.

Call `enqueue` in a normal function:

```
fun makeRequest() {
    getCall().enqueue(
        object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                response: Response<ResponseBody>
            ) {
                
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    //unsuccessful
                }
                //successful
            }
            
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                //failed
            }
            
        }
    )
}
```

or call `execute` in a suspend function on a background thread:

```
suspend fun makeRequest() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val call = getCall()
    
    try {
        val response = call.execute()
        
        if (!response.isSuccessful) {
            //unsuccessful
        }
        
        //successful
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        //failed
    }
}
```

Which one of these is preferable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coroutines have cleaner syntax, so that's a plus. And if you're familiar with coroutine SupervisorJob, you can more easily cancel groups of requests. Other than that, they are largely the same except for which background thread is getting used for the request. But Retrofit already has built-in coroutine support, so your second version can be cleaner than what you have:

```
suspend fun makeRequest() { // Can be called from any dispatcher
    try {
        val response = getCall().awaitResponse()
        
        if (!response.isSuccessful) {
            //unsuccessful
        }
        
        //successful
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        //failed
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know about the `awaitResponse` function because all of the documentation of Retrofit that I found, uses Java. Is there a Kotlin documentation for Retrofit? Or are the Extension functions somewhere else?

Comment: I haven't found it in the documentation. You can look for the KotlinExtensions.kt file in the source to see what's available there. https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/KotlinExtensions.kt  And look at the notes under 2.6.0 in the changelog for how you can make your interfaces use `suspend` functions so they can be used more simply in coroutines (basically, just mark your functions as `suspend`). https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md